# strong animation in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, animation, expression-blend

I want to make an animation in the Silverlight 4 Expression Blend 4 - a running man.
How is it possible to do, because the only way I see it to be done is to draw him frame by frame with the interval, say, 0.2s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options are `bitmap animation` or `key-frame animation` of body parts.

Key-frame animation seems appropriate unless you want photo-realistic movement.

You will need to select regular time internals in Blend and place the various components of the man (legs segments, arm segments etc) in the correct positions for that key frame. Silverlight will do the interpolation between frames.

Build up one complete cycle and set the storyboard property to repeat the sequence.